# Can I bind an onclick event and edit a point in chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2, chartjs-2.6.0

I am using chartjs for making a small project. I am getting some confusion and hard luck in editing the points.

Is there any function in this library I can bind an `onclick` event to which will show me a pop up and I can remove the point?

Here is the summary what I want:

1. Click on the point and a popup appear
2. After clicking on the remove button it removed the point and redraw the point.
   Right now i am only using simple line chart [this is my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rz5r9ag)

I am using chartjs 2.6

Comment: No. that I know of! But you can open up a popup by triggering an event. Show some code for a better opinion.

Comment: i have only a jsfiddle of sample line chart nothing more.

Comment: ok. show the link!

Comment: @funcoding https://jsfiddle.net/5rz5r9ag/

Comment: Yes you can. No pop-up in library but you can make your own. BTW, your question is probably gonna get closed. Better show us *(include in question)* what you've tried *(code wise)* so far to solve it.

Comment: @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ i have added this in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the onclick event in the [option](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html) to show the popup.
Then you can check whether a point was clicked with [getElementsAtEvent](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementatevente) and if so remove it from the options and [update](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#updateconfig) the chart.
I've updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rz5r9ag/12/).

```
var option = {
    showLines: true,
    onClick: function(evt) {   
      var element = myLineChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
      if(element.length > 0)
      {
        var ind = element[0]._index;
        if(confirm('Do you want to remove this point?')){
          data.datasets[0].data.splice(ind, 1);
          data.labels.splice(ind, 1);
          myLineChart.update(data);
        }
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: @Shiftfty Thank you for your response mate. I did not understand the pop up point . I have to include the pop up in the event? Can i use the modal pop up in this ?

Comment: @fatpotato You don't have to include the initialisation of the popup in the event but you have to call its show method. If your modal has a button you can move the code to remove the point and update the chart to the on click event of that button.

Comment: let me test and get back to you

Comment: @fatpotato were you able to test this?

Comment: i am really sorry for not testing it. give me a day to test this. applogies

Comment: @Sgiffty i am really sorry for not accepting it. This works fine as you have said. Thank you :)